# print_list function only prints the first input of the user in the linked list

Tags: c, list, function, printing, linked-list

//Good day. This is just a part of my source code. My main predicament is that the print_list function only prints the first input of the user in the linked list. I can't seem to pin point the problem as the logic of the function seems right. The insert_list function seems to work fine too but  I'm not that sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

//this is the node

```
typedef struct node
{
        char name[61];
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
        struct node *next;
}node;
```

//this is the list

```
typedef struct list
{
        node *head;
        node *tail;
}list;
```

//this creates the node by accepting the user's input and puts them in the node

```
node *create_node()
{
        int x;
        node *data = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Name: ");
        fgets(data->name, 61, stdin);
        printf("Birthdate (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        scanf("%d%*[/]%d%*[/]%d", &data->month, &data->day, &data->year);
        getchar();
        if ((data->month)==0||(data->month)>=13||(data->day)<=0||(data->day)>=32||(data->year)<=1977||(data->year)>=3001)
        {
                while ((data->month)==0||(data->month)>=13||(data->day)<=0||(data->day)>=32||(data->year)<=1977||(data->year)>=3001)
                {
                        printf("Invalid Input.\n");
                        printf("Please Enter a Valid Birthdate(mm/dd/yyyy): \n");
                        scanf("%d%*[/]%d%*[/]%d", &data->month, &data->day, &data->year);
                        getchar();
                }
        }
        printf("******************************************************************\n");
        for (x=0; x<=strlen(data->name); x++)
        {
            if (data->name[x]=='\n')
            {
                    data->name[x]='\0';
            }
    }
    printf("Birthday reminder for %s is added.\n", data->name);
    return data;
}


list *create_list(list *plist)
{
        plist->head = NULL;
        plist->tail = NULL;
        return plist;
}
```

//this inserts the node in the list

```
list *insert_list(list *plist, node *pnode, node *new_node)
{
    if(plist->head==NULL)
    {
            plist->head=new_node;
            new_node->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
            new_node->next = NULL;
            pnode->next = new_node;
            plist->tail = new_node;
    }
    return plist;
}
```

//this prints the list

```
list *print_list(list *plist)
{
        node *current = plist->head;
        int i;
        for(i=1;current!=NULL;i++)
        {    
            printf("[%d] %s\n",i ,current->name);
            printf("Birth Date: %d/%d/%d\n", current->month, current->day, current->year);
            current=current->next;
    }
}
```

//this deallocates the list

```
list *free_list(list *List)
{
    node *current = List->head;
    node *temp = NULL;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
            temp = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(temp);
    }

    List->head = NULL;
    List->tail = NULL;
}
```

//this is the main

```
int main(void)
{
        list* List = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
        List = create_list(List);
        char x;
        node *data = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("******************************************************************\n");
        printf("                    ADD BIRTHDAY REMINDER FORM\n");
        printf("******************************************************************\n");
        List = insert_list(List, data, create_node(data));
        printf("Would you like to add another(y/n)?\n");
        scanf("%c", &x);
        if (x=='y')
        {
                while (x=='y')
                {
                        if (x=='y')
                        {
                                getchar();
                            printf("******************************************************************\n");
                                node *data = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
                                List = insert_list(List, data, create_node(data));
                                printf("Would you like to add another(y/n)?\n");
                                scanf("%c", &x);
                        }
                }
        }
    print_list(List);
    free(List);
    return 0;

}
```

//this code is ready for compilling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand, what do you intend by `pnode`in `insert_list`, and I guess, there is the error. Probably, you mean something like *previous node*. However, the tail *is* already the previous node. In addition, you use an empty node there, even you alloc memory for a node in `create_node`. Maybe, the following code would be more appropriate:

```
list *insert_list(list *plist, node *new_node)
{
    if(plist->head==NULL)
    {
            plist->head=new_node;
            plist->tail=new_node;
            new_node->next=NULL;

    }
    else
    {
            new_node->next = NULL;
            plist->tail->next = new_node;
            plist->tail = new_node;
    }
    return plist;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I used that as the previous node. I tried replacing my insert list code with yours but it still printed only one of the inputs.

Comment: Well, I guess you have to adapt the calling code, too. BTW, which is printed, the still first or the last one?

Comment: I'm very sorry, your code works fine, I was compiling the wrong program :))) Thank you and God Bless! :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you pasted your actual source?
in `List = insert_list(List, data, create_node(data));` you call `create_node(data)` but you function `node *create_node()` takes zero arguments. I dont understand the purpose of `node *pnode` argument in `list *insert_list(list *plist, node *pnode, node *new_node)

The print function seems legit to me. Try compiling with -Wall -Wextra -Werror for extra error detection.
`

Comment: yup I did but the errors there didn't address the print function predicament

Comment: well, that create_node(data) seems as bad call and i think that code below from @Matthias solves the problem with inserting. Try using @Matthias function with `List = insert_list(List, create_node());`

Comment: thank you for telling me about create_node(data) being a bad call. But i tried both of your suggestions but the print function still prints only one output

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why the second argument `pnode` is needed for `insert_list`.
If you just want to print all elements in a list, I think the following modification can fix your problem:

First, add a line `plist->tail=new_node` into the first if-clause of `insert_list`.
Second, change the second argument of `insert_list` from `data` to `List->tail` in `main`.

And there is another unimportant thing I would like to point out. Do you really need the condition `if (x == 'y)` in `main`? I don't know why it is there.

Comment: Hi, I already took out the data argument in the main as the other's said it served no purpose as the create node function it self creates its own node data already.